# is it possible to create an append query that inserts a variable value and a table field at the same time?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create an append query that inserts a declared variable's value along with a field value into a table ,i used the term "VALUES" in the code and it works if am inserting the variable only,mixing it with "SELECT ....." will give me an error.This is a simple version of my code :

```
X = 99999
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Change_history_tbl ( [emp_name],[emp_salary] ) " & _
 "SELECT emplyees.emp_name FROM emplyees ,values(" & X & ") " & _
 "WHERE (((emplyees.emp_name)=[Forms]![Form1]![emp_name]));"
```

the code should append the employee name and his salary into the table (Change_history_tbl) ,tried other scenario of this code ,all with no luck.
Is it do able?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
X = 99999
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Change_history_tbl ( [emp_name],[emp_salary] ) " & _
 "SELECT emplyees.emp_name, " & X & " FROM emplyees " & _
 "WHERE (((emplyees.emp_name)=[Forms]![Form1]![emp_name]));"
```